# Create dynamic component based on string in Angular 5

Tags: angular

Let say I've got an API that gives me this :

```
{
   title: 'title1',
   type: 'FullComponent'
},
{
   title: 'title2',
   type: 'HalfComponent'
},
{
   title: 'title3',
   type: 'HalfComponent'
},
{
   title: 'title4',
   type: 'ThirdComponent'
},
{
   title: 'title5',
   type: 'ThirdComponent'
},
{
   title: 'title6',
   type: 'ThirdComponent'
},
```

I want to dynamically generate components based on those `type` value.

```
// app.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
    this.getWidget()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
        },
        error => {
          ???
        }
     );
}

getWidget() {
  return this.http.get('www.api.com');
}
```

`data` returns the json above.
What should I do to generate these components (these components have already been created with Angular CLI, so they already exist)?
Thanks :)

Comment: but all these components are expected to be in the `entryComponents` of the module

Comment: Help me understand this, you get components list from an API and then you prepare your application with these components and use the app? Have i got it right?

Comment: I already created all three components in my app's architecture. I just want to generate those based on string value from API. So I want to create a Components Generator that will do something like this : `<full-component></full-component><half-component></half-component><half-component></half-component><thrid-component></thrid-component><thrid-component></thrid-component><thrid-component></thrid-component>`

Answer (score -2):

I'd create a component manager that would render FullComponent, HalfComponent or ThirdComponent in function of an input:

`manager.component.html`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="component === 'FullComponent'">
  <app-full-component></app-full-component>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="component === 'HalfComponent'">
  <app-half-component></app-half-component>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="component === 'ThirdComponent'">
  <app-third-component></app-third-component>
</ng-container>
```

`manager.component.ts` should have an input:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-manager',
templateUrl: './manager.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./manager.component.css']
})
export class ManagerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() component: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In your `app.component.ts` you pass data to an array:

```
// app.component.ts

data: Any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getWidget()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.data = data;
        },
        error => {
          ???
        }
     );
}

getWidget() {
  return this.http.get('www.api.com');
}
```

Finally, in `app.component.html` you call a `*ngFor` which iterates over data and pass `type` to manager component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let d of data'>
  <app-manager [component]="d.type"></app-manager>
</ng-container>
```